# How to add folder inside src/main/app in Mule project directly inside zip file and not in classes when building using maven

Tags: maven, mule, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a folder named `webapps` inside my `src/main/app` in mule project. This `webapps` folder contains a `war` which is exposed in `mule-config.xml` through `jetty connector`. I tried lot of combinations in my maven build but this webapps folder ends up inside `classes` in `zip` file. I want it right inside `zip`.

Any pointers how to achieve it in `pom`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since couldn't get `maven` to build `zip` file in a way that it would copy `webapps` folder directly under root. I ended up placing `webapps` folder containing `war` file inside `src/main/resources`. Maven build copied `webapps` folder under classes. And the `mule-config` referred it as

```
<jetty:connector name="Jetty" doc:name="Jetty">
    <jetty:webapps port="${jetty.port}" host="${jetty.host}" directory="${app.home}/classes/webapps" /> 
</jetty:connector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the maven ant plugin.

File can be moved around after compilation and before packaging.
phase: prepare-package (just before packing)

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-ant.html

Hope this helps.